# Firefox/IE only - gif animation frozen after element show() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gif

I have a page that has a gif animation in a hidden div.  Upon clicking something the div show()s but the animation is stuck on the first frame.  I have tried a few fixes but nothing seems to work.  I have tried inserting the image dynamically when clicked, refocusing, etc. to no avail.

To see the example go to http://staging.trulioo.com and choose a different language using the language selector at the top.  The word "Translating" and and animated image should appear.  The animation does work in all other browsers other than IE and Firefox (wtf?) ...

Comment: What is supposed to be animated?

Comment: @Fresheyeball the little "circle/arrows" thing - the problem seems to be that Firefox is just uninterested in doing the animation on a page that's about to be overwritten by the results of an HTTP request.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Left to the language "select" you'll see a text *Translating* and a *loading* gif

Comment: Please add that to your question. Its key.

Comment: Maybe you could have the "click" handler for the "switch language" buttons reveal the hidden `<div>` and then start the page reload from a timeout handler a few milliseconds after the "click".

Comment: The problem is that the spinning arrows next to "Translating ..." do not spin on IE or Firefox.

Comment: Changing language is triggering a full page refresh. Correct?

Comment: Can you tell me how the gif is loaded? are you doing show()/hide() on the img tag itself? edit - nvm I saw the code, you are showing and hiding the div. I had a problem where I was doing showing/hiding on the img tag and it had the same issue on some browsers but it's not the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this to work trying several solutions.  My final solution was to switch from a gif animation to a JavaScript solution in spin.js.  It works great!!

http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

Comment: (late to the party) I was using spin.js to fix this until figured it out the real problem. See here how keep using spinner.gif animation on all browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521382/how-do-you-display-animated-gifs-within-a-jquery-dialog-in-ie/15645028#15645028

Answer (score 1):

Try to show the element initially when the DOM is built. Maybe use css to put it off page and simply put it back to where it supposed to be when you need it. Or maybe use opacity to hide it, either way make sure the element is shown on page load.

Source - http://www.norio.be/blog/2008/09/animated-gif-not-working-internet-explorer

Comment: @JamesHuckabone can you provide a fiddle how you tried this? a simplified example, I am sure we can get this to work

Comment: Same problem here. I don't think it has a solution, this is intrinsic to Firefox's way of rendering GIF images. It works fin in other browsers.

Comment: I have had this problem before and it was solved without using additional js.