# GIF does not animate in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.ajax').on('click', function(){

    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
        $('#modal').dialog('destroy');
        $('#modal').html(data);
        $('#modal').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width:'auto',
        });
    })
    showModal();
    return false;

});
function showModal() {

    $('#modal').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif">');

    $('#modal').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width:'auto',
        height: 90
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
}
```

In chrome `loading.gif` does not animate, in firefox `loading.gif` shows, then immediately hides, and after 3 seconds display new modal. What is the problem?

Also I want to ask- is any way to use the same dialog, first display gif, then smoothly resize to new dialog and centered it?

Update

```
$('.ajax').on('click', function(){
showModal();
return false;
});
function showModal() {
$('#modal').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif">');

$('#modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width:'auto',
    height: 90
});
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

}

This code animate gif good, so the problem is not with the dialog

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521382/how-do-you-display-animated-gifs-within-a-jquery-dialog-in-ie